# How can I get autocomplete/intellisense features for Firefox extension APIs on vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, firefox-addon-webextensions, javascript-intellisense

I am developing my first firefox extension on vscode and just discovered that autocomplete/intellisense isn't working for web extension APIs e.g. `browser.tab`, `browser.extension` like it does for regular JavaScript. I like the intellisense feature because it minimizes errors and docs consultation. A google search result suggested I add:

```
{
  "typeAcquisition": {
     "include": ["firefox"]
  }
}
```

in a **jsconfig.json** file which I've done but the issue still persists. Is there a way I can get intellisense to work here or am I out of luck?

Comment: Use DefinitelyTyped `firefox-webext-browser` package or find an alternative, I see a few.

Answer (score 3):

Create a `jsconfig.json` file in your source and add this line to it ⤵︎

```json
{"typeAcquisition": {"include": ["firefox-webext-browser"]}}
```

You should then have suggestions for the `browser` namespace.